# Every time i open a file with jedit text editor, large buffer warning pops up

Tags: jedit

I use *jEdit* very often to open my xml files. It so happened that once i tried opening a huge file(around **900MB** file size, say xyz.xml) with jEdit, which failed.
From then on, every time i open any file(file size< 1MB) with jedit text editor, large buffer warning pops up:
**The buffer is very large and jEdit may become unresponsive.**
Can anybody help me how to resolve this problem. Is the only way out for this is to reinstall the editor?

Comment: I have checked jEdit sites for the same, couldnt find any solution for this issue though.

Answer (score 0):

JEdit doesn't support very large files very well.  You can increase the size that JEdit is allowed to use inside of Java by changing [java's heap size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java) when you launch jedit like this:

```
java -Xmx512m -jar /FOO/BAR/jedit.jar
```

If increasing the memory size doesn't work for your largest files, you should try another editor.  [`vim`](http://www.vim.org/download.php) performs very well with very large files.

Comment: Thanks Ross. I tried changing the heap size as you have mentioned. It gives the following error:  **jEdit: inifPLAF failed to set required l&f**

Comment: I checked for this error on jedit sites. They have a bug reported which looks similar to this. Here is the link: (http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3520566&group_id=588&atid=100588).

Comment: Alaka,  I really recommend using a different editor for ridiculously large files.  JEdit simply isn't built for that.  vi and vim were built in a time when everything seemed like a ridiculously large file since the computers were so weak compared to today.  Thus, they handle large files pretty well.

Comment: Sure Ross.. I will do that. But my problem presently is, I am currently opening files of small sizes(less than 1 MB). Even while I try opening this file, it throws the buffer error(thrown previously while opening the large file). The strange part is the error thrown shows the large filename. However, looks like i better switch to different editor. Thanks again.

Comment: Close all your buffers with `File`->`Close All` , and restart JEdit.  JEdit attempts to open all your buffers from the last session, so you're probably trying to open the big file every time you boot.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this, constantly seeing this large buffer warning is very annoying, I have over 100GB of memory on the machine I'm using so the "may become unresponsive stuff" really doesn't happen much.

You can turn off the warning message by going to
Utilities->Global Options->Large Files-> and checking "Keep Full Syntax" under the question "what should I do about very big files..."